# perform in-rotated-rectangle test and get many outliers

Tags: python, cuda, linear-algebra

I write a cuda program that decides if a point P is inside a rectangle ABCD or not by checking the inner product with the directed edged of rectangle, which is in clockwise order. As is shown below, CP * CD >0 if and only if P is below line BC, and DP * DA>0 if and only if P is to the left of CD, etc. So by doing 4 inner product we can filter all points inside(or on) this rectangle with their product values greater than or equal to 0. [outliers here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVZmn.png)

```
                 __P
                  /|
   B ___________\C
  /|\           /|     
   |             |  
   |             |    
   | /__________\|/  
   A \        D  _\|
                    P
```

What troubles me is that when I experiment this codes on my data, a triangle area outside this rectangle is also marked as inside, which I can't explain.

```
__global__ void inBoxKernel(const float *A, const float *B, int *C, int numElements){
    int i = (blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x)*2;
    float t11;
    float t12;
    float t21;
    float t22;
    if (i/2 < numElements)
    {
        if ((A[i]<B[0] || (A[i] >B[4]))||((A[i+1]>B[3]) || (A[i+1] <B[7])))
            {
                C[i/2]=-1;
            }
        else
        {
           t11=(A[i]-B[0])*(B[2]-B[0])+(A[i+1]-B[1])*(B[3]-B[1]);
           t12=(A[i]-B[4])*(B[6]-B[4])+(A[i+1]-B[5])*(B[7]-B[5]);
           t21=(A[i]-B[2])*(B[4]-B[2])+(A[i+1]-B[3])*(B[5]-B[3]);
           t22=(A[i]-B[6])*(B[2]-B[6])+(A[i+1]-B[7])*(B[1]-B[7]);
           if (t11>=1e-5 && t12>=1e-5 && t21>=1e-5 && t22>=1e-5) 
           {
                C[i/2]=1;
           }
           else
           {
                C[i/2]=-1;
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to debug with one of the outliers as an input to understand what is going wrong?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As a beginner I didn't come up with that, because writing a gpu program is not a easy task. Now I wrote a cpu version and easily checked what was going on. A mistake in calculating t22=(A[i]-B[6])*(B[2]-B[6])+... leads to the problem, where B[2] should be replaced by B[0].

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a cpu version and checked what was going on. A mistake in calculating t22=(A[i]-B[6])*(B[2]-B[6])+... leads to the problem, where B[2] should be replaced by B[0]. The resulting wrong vector is close to the right one so only a small number of points are out of the rect, especially when the rotation angle is small.